# Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder

Tags: php, database

```
//Get Services and save to database first.
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["wc_service_id"]); $i++) {
    $wc_service_id          = $_POST["wc_service_id"][$i];
    $wc_service_name        = $_POST["wc_service_name"][$i];

    $wc_service_code        = $_POST["wc_service_code"][$i];
    $wc_service_qty         = $_POST["wc_service_qty"][$i];
    $wc_service_price       = $_POST["wc_service_price"][$i];

    $insert_query =  "INSERT INTO `".$computer_repair_items."` VALUES(NULL, '".$wc_service_name."', 'services', '".$post_id."')";
     $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare($insert_query)
    );
    $order_item_id = $wpdb->insert_id;


    $insert_query =  "INSERT INTO `".$computer_repair_items_meta."` 
                        VALUES(NULL, '".$order_item_id."', 'wc_service_code', '".$wc_service_code."'), 
                        (NULL, '".$order_item_id."', 'wc_service_id', '".$wc_service_id."'),
                        (NULL, '".$order_item_id."', 'wc_service_qty', '".$wc_service_qty."'), 
                        (NULL, '".$order_item_id."', 'wc_service_price', '".$wc_service_price."')";
    $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare($insert_query)
    );
}//Services Processed nicely
```

With code above its working completely fine only problem i am getting this Notice: when debug mode is on. And i shouldn't have any notices.

Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder.

Is there any suggestion? I know removing prepare( would take away the problem. But i want to keep the query prepared if you think its not necessary please explain.

Also adding %s, %d for first query, is good. But what for 2nd Query where i have 3 values?

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You don't need to remove the `prepare()`, but you just need to do it properly.*

And please check the `$wpdb->prepare()` [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) for the function's syntax etc., but basically, instead of (wrapped for brevity):

```php
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `".$computer_repair_items."`
    VALUES(NULL, '".$wc_service_name."', 'services', '".$post_id."')";
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($insert_query)
);
```

you should do it like this: (presuming `$computer_repair_items` is a valid table name)

```php
$insert_query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `$computer_repair_items` VALUES(NULL, %s, 'services', %d)",
    $wc_service_name, // 2nd parameter; replaces the %s (first placeholder)
    $post_id          // 3rd parameter; replaces the %d (second placeholder)
);
$wpdb->query( $insert_query );
```

I.e. You *must* pass at least two parameters to `$wpdb->prepare()`:

1. The **first parameter** is the SQL command and should be in the same format as accepted by the PHP's [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function, i.e. using placeholders such as `%s` for strings and `%d` for integers.
2. The second parameter should be the replacement value for the first placeholder in the SQL command mentioned above, i.e. the first parameter. So in the example I gave, the second parameter is `$wc_service_name` which the value replaces the `%s` in the SQL command. *But note that you should **not** wrap the placeholder in quotes, so `'%s'` and `"%s"` for examples, are incorrect and just use `%s`.*
3. Depending on your SQL command, you can also have the third, fourth, fifth, etc. parameters, just as in the example I gave where I have a third parameter which is `$post_id` for the `%d` placeholder.

And actually, for **single** `INSERT` operations, you could simply use [`$wpdb->insert()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/):

```php
// Make sure you replace the column NAMES.
$wpdb->insert( $computer_repair_items, [
    'column'  => $wc_service_name,
    'column2' => 'services',
    'column3' => $post_id,
] );
```

For multiple inserts, you can try something like:

```php
$insert_values = [];
foreach ( [
    [ 'wc_service_code', $wc_service_code ],
    [ 'wc_service_id', $wc_service_id ],
    [ 'wc_service_qty', $wc_service_qty ],
    [ 'wc_service_price', $wc_service_price ],
] as $row ) {
    $insert_values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(NULL, %d, %s, %s)",
        $order_item_id, $row[0], $row[1] );
}

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `$computer_repair_items_meta`
    VALUES " . implode( ',', $insert_values );
$wpdb->query( $insert_query );
```

Or just call `$wpdb->insert()` multiple times..

Comment: Thanks for your answer its really very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! And I should add that the *`n$` position specifier* (e.g. `%2$s`) is not supported by `wpdb::prepare()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is extremely unsafe.

You're not using `$wpdb->prepare()` properly. You can't just use it on a string as a magic fix. There is nothing in this line of code that protects you from SQL injection attacks, because you're taking submitted values from `$_POST` and inserting them directly into an SQL query:

```
"INSERT INTO `".$computer_repair_items."` VALUES(NULL, '".$wc_service_name."', 'services', '".$post_id."')";
```

The whole point of `$wpdb->prepare()`, [as documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#protect-queries-against-sql-injection-attacks), is to safely insert variables into an SQL query. To do this you need to provide it 2 things:

1. An SQL string with placeholders where the variables need to go.
2. The variables that will go into those placeholders, separately.

So instead of:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `".$computer_repair_items."` VALUES(NULL, '".$wc_service_name."', 'services', '".$post_id."')";
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($insert_query)
);
```

You need to do this:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `{$computer_repair_items}` VALUES( NULL, %s, 'services', %s )";

$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare( $insert_query, $wc_service_name, $post_id );
);
```

Note that:

- `$wpdb->prepare()` can't insert the table name from a variable, but the table name should not be coming from an unsafe source. I'm assuming that you've defined in manually in your code earlier.
- The first `%s` will be replaced with a safely escaped version of `$wc_service_name`, with quotes added automatically.
- The second `%s` will be replaced with a safely escaped version of `$post_id`, with quotes added automatically, just because this is what your original code did. If that column is actually an integer column, then use `%d` instead of `%s`.

All that being said, `$wpdb` actually has [a method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) for `INSERT` queries that automatically prepares the query for you. For our example you would use it like this:

```
$wpdb->insert(
    $computer_repair_items,
    [
        $wc_service_name,
        $post_id,
    ],
    [
        '%s',
        '%s',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its really very helpful.